# Will a randomly moving point traverse every integer point on the plane as the number of steps it takes approaches infinity?

Tags: probability, limits

Question is pretty much in the title, but a few specifications: 
-define the starting point as the origin, or define the origin as the starting point, either should do nicely
-the distance moved is always 1 unit
-the plane is unbounded; of course if this were a bounded torus, the answer would just be "yeah" and I've already proven this but I want to know about an unbounded plane.
-what about a point which is n steps from the origin? what's the expected average number of steps it will take to get there?
-what about a point which moves a predetermined number of steps? what's the probability it will visit a given point n steps away from it?
-what about if it moves a random distance between 0 and 1, and is no longer bounded to points described by integer pairs? does that affect any of these as the number of steps goes to infinity?

In general, this randomly walking point on a plane has a lot of interesting properties and any discussion of its other interesting properties would be invited too if it could provide some general insight into the nature of this construction.

EDIT: Would a single-dimensional analogue of this problem have similar properties? What about expanding the problem into 3d? Do generalizations into higher dimensions have similar answers, or do the answers or the ways of finding them change drastically?

Answer (score 0):

It is well known that a simple random walk in $\mathbb{Z}^d$ is recurrent if and only if $d=1,2$.

Assuming $d=1, 2$, since you have a positive probability to get from the origin to any point, and almost surely you will visit the origin infinite number of times everything will be covered.

To see the details for this, and many other related questions see for example, Probability: Theory and Examples (by Durrett).